# Sharepoint document library as a destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I create a CSV-file from SSIS and I want to "publish it" in a specific folder in our Sharepoint document library. What is the preferred way to this?

I have looked at the example with the sharepoint list destination [SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://www.codeplex.com/SQLSrvIntegrationSrv/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=17652)  which is quite good but not exactly what I'm out for. I just want to upload a file to the document library from within SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses WEBDAV to provide a folder like locations. You can see an example of this by going to the list in question and selecting actions-> open with explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to send an email to the doc library.

The doc lib owner needs to set up the email address on the page options, this will give you an email that looks like

xxxx@moss.domain.com

If the folder ever gets moved around, as long as the email remains, you don't need to worry about it